# Change orientation based on Scroll event in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to change orientation of recyclerview based on user's scroll up/down or left/right action. Here is my onCreate() method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(totalItemCount));

    // default orientation is VERTICAL
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, spanCount, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener listener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            Log.i("TAG", "current orientation: " + gridLayoutManager.getOrientation());

            if (dx > 0) {
                Log.i("TAG", "dx = " + dx);
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
                    }
                });

            } else if (dy > 0) {
                Log.i("TAG", "dy = " + dy);
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    }
                });
            }
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        }
    };

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(listener);
}
```

The issue is that it does not change orientation in recyclerview. Is it right approach to change orientation?

**EDIT**

There is no exception after suggested code modification (by @RobCo). But I can not change orientation still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is very clear:

> Cannot call this method in a scroll callback. Scroll callbacks might be run during a measure & layout pass where you cannot change theRecyclerView data. Any method call that might change the structure of the RecyclerView or the adapter contents should be postponed to the next frame.

So, `setOrientation` cannot be called from a layout or measure pass, or during a scroll callback.   You'll have to post a Runnable to the next frame:

```
    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, there is no exception now but orientation is not changing